# Evaluating a limit involving nested radica

Tags: calculus, limits, derivatives

The problem asks to evaluate this limit :

$$\lim\limits_{x \to 2} \dfrac{\sqrt{2+\sqrt{2+\sqrt{2+\cdots+\sqrt{2+x}}}}-2}{x-2}$$

Where the expression consists of $n$ nested radicals.

My approach was **using induction**. Denoting by $L_n$ the limit, one can show by induction that $(L_n)$ is geometric of common ratio $\dfrac 1 4$ yielding that the limit is but $\left( \dfrac 1 4\right)^n$.

I tried to evaluate the same limit using the definition of the derivative of the function :

$$f_n(x)=\sqrt{2+\sqrt{2+\sqrt{2+\cdots+\sqrt{2+x}}}}$$

which is differentiable in $(-2,+\infty)$ and therefore differentiable at $2$.

I'm having a problem in calculating the derivative of this function.

thanks.

Comment: Multiply and divide by $\sqrt{\square}_k+2$, for $k=n,n-1,n-2,...1$, where $\sqrt{\square}_k$ is the radical in your limit.

Comment: thanks @user85667 but my question about how to compute the derivative of $f_n$.

Comment: It may help you to try the substitution $x=2\cos t$, $t\to0$. If there are $n$ nested square roots, the nested root in the numerator simplifies to $2\cos(t/2^n)$.

Comment: If you are trying to get the derivative from the definition, it is computing the same limit but with $x\to$some other value and the value of $-f_n$ instead of the $-2$ of the numerator. The same idea would apply. If you are computing using properties of the derivative, you can apply the chain rule. Note that the chain rule gives $f_n'(x)=\frac{1}{2}\frac{1}{f_n(x)}f_{n-1}'(x)$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Call $g_0(x)=x$ and $g_n(x)=\sqrt{2+g_{n-1}(x)}$. Notice that $g_n(2)=2$ for all $n$. Now notice that what you want is exactly $g'_n(2)$. For $x>-2$ you have $g_n'(x)=\frac{g_{n-1}'(x)}{2g_n(x)}$. We can prove by induction that for all $k\le n$ we have $g'_n(x)=\frac{g'_{n-k}(x)}{2^k\prod_{j=0}^{k-1}g_{n-j}(x)}$. Therefore $g'_n(x)=\frac{1}{2^n\prod_{j=1}^n g_j(x)}$. Since $g_j(2)=2$ for all $j$, we have that $g'_n(2)=4^{-n}$.